# GDAL "permission denied" on Windows

Tags: python, gdal, image, windows, satellite

```py
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Open('/Data/F182010.v4/F182010.v4d_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif', gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
```

The code showing Runtime Error Permission denied How to fix this?

```py
/Data/F182010.v4/F182010.v4d_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif: **Permission denied**
```

Comment: Try to put your data in a folder with write permission.

Comment: That folder already has the write permission.